# Is it possible to specify a region when using ec2.describeManagedPrefixLists? (JavaScript AWS-SDK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a few different managed prefix lists across different regions in my AWS account that I want to list. I'm trying to iterate over a list of regions that I've pulled with `ec2.describeRegions`, but I can't see a way to pass them in as parameters to `ec2.describeManagedPrefixLists`.

It's not listed as a possible parameter [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeManagedPrefixLists-property), and if I try to pass in a known Prefix List ID from a region other than the one specified with the initial `AWS.config.update({region:'example-region'})`, it'll tell me it doesn't exist.

I'm currently manually resetting `AWS.config.update({region:'example-region'})` each time my loop runs, but it's painfully slow:

```
for (let i = 0; i < regions.length; i++){
    AWS.config.update({region: regions[i]});
    let ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
    // ec2.describeManagedPrefixLists(params, ...)
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I did solve the speed issue by creating seperate EC2 objects for each region. As a dumbed-down example:

```
ec2_A = new AWS.EC2(({ region: 'us-east-1'}));
ec2_B = new AWS.EC2(({ region: 'us-east-2'}));

ec2_A.describeManagedPrefixLists(params, function(err, data){...}
ec2_B.describeManagedPrefixLists(params, function(err, data){...}
```